# Storing text values in Variable of previous nodes

Tags: xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

Input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XML>
    <Concept>
        <Heading-1>This is First Heading</Heading-1>
    </Concept>
    <Concept>
        <Heading-2>This is Second Heading</Heading-2>
    </Concept>
    <Concept>
        <Heading-2>This is First Heading</Heading-2>
    </Concept>
 </XML>
```

Output should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<name>This_is_First_Heading</name>
<name>This_is_Second_Heading</name>
<name>1_This_is_First_Heading</name>
```

Stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="Concept">
        <xsl:variable name="name" 
                      select="./Heading-1/text() | ./Heading-2/text()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="name1" 
                      select="if //Cocept/Heading-1/text()=$name 
                              then concat(position(), '_' $name)} 
                              else $name"/>
        <name>
            <xsl:value-of select="replace($name, ' ', '_' )"/>
        </name>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Problem: I need to print all the heading text values under "name" element. But if there is similar text value present for previous hading it should add position() number before the text values. I need to do it though variable only, if you can see in Variable name1 i am trying to put some logic which will compare the value of previous heading and if come across the similar text then put the position number, but somehow am not able to achieve that. Can you please help me write same logic in variable name1. Thanks in advance for your help.

__*_*___*Edited****_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
<xsl:template match="Concept">
    <xsl:variable name="name"
                  select="if (./Heading-1[1] |
                              ./Heading-2[1] |
                              ./Heading-3[1] |
                              ./Heading-4[1] |
                              ./Heading-5[1])
                          then normalize-space((Heading-1[1] |
                                                Heading-2[1] |
                                                Heading-3[1] |
                                                Heading-4[1] |
                                                Heading-5[1])
                                                /text()[position()=last()])
                          else normalize-space(./Heading-2[1]/text()[2])"/>
        <xsl:variable name="name1"
                      select="if (//Concept/Heading-3/text()
                                   [position()=last()] = $name)
                              then concat(position(), '_', $name)
                              else $name"></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="name2"
                      select="if (string-length($name5)=0)
                              then concat(position(), '_', $name5)
                              else $name5"/>
        <xsl:result-document href="XML/{replace($name2, ' ', '_')}.xml"
                             format="testing" validation="strip">
```

Comment: Can you post the input and the stylesheet as XML please? And then explain whether you want to tranform the XML input to XML, or HTML, to XHTML or to plain text.

Comment: Your edit makes no sense to me...

Comment: @Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and very short solution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One of the simplest possible XSLT 2.0 solutions**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:template match="/*/*/*">
  <name>
    <xsl:sequence select=
     "concat(for $cnt in count(../preceding-sibling::*/*[. eq current()])
              return 
                if($cnt gt 0)
                  then concat($cnt, '_')
                  else (),
              .
             )
     "/>
  </name>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<XML>
    <Concept>
        <Heading-1>This is First Heading</Heading-1>
    </Concept>
    <Concept>
        <Heading-2>This is Second Heading</Heading-2>
    </Concept>
    <Concept>
        <Heading-2>This is First Heading</Heading-2>
    </Concept>
 </XML>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<name>This is First Heading</name>
<name>This is Second Heading</name>
<name>1_This is First Heading</name>
```

**In case you need each of the text nodes produced in the result to be actually in variables**, then simply replace in the above code `<xsl:sequence>` with `<xsl:variable>`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample stylesheet that produces the result you asked for:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="k1" match="Concept/*" use="."/>

  <xsl:template match="Concept/*">
    <xsl:variable name="preceding" select="key('k1', .)[. &lt;&lt; current()]"/>
    <name>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$preceding">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(count($preceding), '_', replace(., ' ', '_'))"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="replace(., ' ', '_')"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </name>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: +1 Good answer. But I would use `concat(concat(count($preceding),'_')[$preceding],replace(.,' ', '_'))` to make it less verbose.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need your help in implementing this solution in my actual scenario.. I am creating chunk xml files based on these heading names. And now my context node is "Concept" not "Concept/*". Can you help me achive the same in below stylesheet:

Comment: I have updated my question with edited tag.. I need to use this logic in "xsl:result-document" to avoid ducplicate file name. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Pankaj, You will need to explain in more detail what you want to achieve with xsl:result-document, maybe even in a new question.

Comment: I apologies for not being clear in my question. But to give more clarity on the requirement that my context node is "Concept" and want to write the same logic within this context node. I am trying to analyse the scenario again and post new question with specific question soon. Thanks for all your help. Pankaj